# Uploading images to Remote Server, iPhone

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I would like to take images from library, or camera and upload them to a remote server, where I could then retreieve a URL for each image uploaded.

Im looking to get started from scratch. And am looking for some help on where to start.

Im need to do this the simplest way, php and mysql.
Where should I start?!

Also, I rather not use any third partys for this.

Just simple,

How do i DB connect, 
Insert
Read
Done!

Let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I ROCK!

and this guy too. http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/

Heres what I implemented

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
// setting up the URL to post to
NSString *urlString = @"myurl/insert.php";

// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

/*
 now lets create the body of the post
 */
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(returnString);
```

As for the PHP it looks like.

```
   <?php
       $uploaddir = './uploads/';
   $file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
   $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "myurl/uploads/{$file}";
      } 
?>
```

Boss!!!
@lessfame

Comment: Note, this purely uploads the photo to an upload folder. 
My next task is to use a Custom name, and store the URL and file name in a DB.

WOOOO!

Comment: this row : [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; not action, <br> debug : ($_FILES['userfile']['name']) is null

Comment: Well, but what do you do if youn want to replace "ipodfile.jpg" with a variable?