# how to upload image in php using iOS

Tags: php, ios, image, upload

i am new in web services in php i don't now what is the behavior of ios to upload image so i write down my PHP code can anybody help me what is wrong in php code or there something wrong in ios code

```
$picName = $_FILES['name']['pic_data'];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'images/'.$picName);
```

Comment: It may be helpful Please go through this [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367930/uploading-images-to-remote-server-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx Alot i know what i do wrong so thanx to ernaidu and asad Mahmood

this Wrong::

```
$picName = $_FILES['name']['pic_data'];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'images/'.$picName);
```

This is right::

```
$picName = $_FILES['pic_data']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic_data"]["tmp_name"], '../images/'.$picName);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you must be sending like this:

```
xhrRegister.send({ file : selectedPhoto });
```

and you can get it in PHP like this:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  // ERROR
} else {
  $filename = uniqid() . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  $filetype = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'images/' . $filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refer the below link to know how to upload image and use mysql to manage it.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13511/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-12
http://www.raywenderlich.com/13541/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-22